# Cannot load remote webpage in mvc modal

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I can successfully load a local page into a modal preview:

```
             $('.preview-button').click(function () {
                 $('#dialog').dialog('open');
                 $('#dialog').load("@Url.Action("Index", "LatestNews", new {area = "Home"})");
             });
```

But I cannot load a remote webpage, say "http://www.example.com/home/php".
Moreover, when links in the embedded contents of modal page are click, the user leaves the modal altogether.

1. How can I embed a remote web page in an mvc (jquery modal)?
2. How can I keep the user in the modal when they click the links in the embedded remote page in the modal?

Thank You.

Comment: **1.** you can't send ajax request to a different domain. security reasons.

Comment: Sadly you'll need to use iframe's if you want to be able to handle the others sites content (links etc). And that basicly never a good soloution. You can use GET on crossdomain, so that shouldnt be a problem, you just need to use `crossDomain: true` in your ajax call

Comment: know of any links explaining this procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
$('.preview-button').click(function () {
$('#dialog').dialog('open').html('<iframe id="modalIframeId" width="100%" height="100%" marginWidth="0"
 marginHeight="0" frameBorder="0" scrolling="auto" />');
 $("#modalIframeId").attr("src","http://www.blahblahblah.com/default.asp");
                return false;
            });
        });
     </script>

<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title" />
```